# How to get the old ASCII characters table CP437

Tags: ascii

I use Ubuntu Studio 19.10 and, even the fact that today we have a lot of new technologies, apps, etc... I really love to use old technology (DOSBox, HATARI, etc).

In that line, I want to know how to get the old ASCII characters table, the "standard" CP437.

I'm talking about to use, inside some today Linux app (let's say LibreOffice), the ASCII CP437 graphics characters with decimal code beyond 127.

Is there some Linux command to this?

Or... What do I have to use to get it?

Comment: There is `ascii`, but my search for CP437 tells me it's not exactly what you want, right? Very useful, though.

Comment: ASCII is a 7-bit charset. CP437 is an 8-bit one that extends the high 128 code points. They're not the same. There's no such thing as "ASCII characters table CP437"

Comment: phuclv, I'm talking about this... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437

Comment: Have a look at https://superuser.com/questions/278286/making-256-color-and-line-drawing-characters-both-work-in-putty  Is that close to what you are looking for?  That is from a putty console from Windows.  You could do the same with xterm

Comment: @Juan of course I know about that, and it's not ASCII. And please use `@` when addressing anyone, otherwise they won't be notified

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice @phuclv I didn't know this @ tricks. Thanks!