# How to print the ■ character in linux terminal using C?

Tags: c, character-set

This char is 254 in ASCII Extended Table, and 25A0 in Unicode. If I run `putchar(254)` the terminal does not recognize the char, as I think it utilizes not extended ASCII.

Comment: Which character set is your terminal using? [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)? [windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)? [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)? [ISO 8859-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15)? [JIS X 0201](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIS_X_0201)? There is no single "extended ASCII Table", so without knowing what character set your system uses, "254" has no meaning I'm afraid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printf("■\n");` works for me - `putchar('■');` gives me a warning about multi-character character constants. `putchar(254);` gives me a 'þ' character.
Also, make sure the terminal emulator you are using supports unicode.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as “the extended ASCII”. There are tens, if not hundreds, of 8-bit encodings based on ASCII. Many of them are available on Ubuntu, but they are not commonly used. The modern computing world, Ubuntu or not, uses the [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) character set, generally encoded as [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Unicode is a 32-bit character set and UTF-8 encodes each 32-bit code point as one to four 8-bit bytes.

If character 254 is ■, you probably want one of the 8-bit encoding used in the text mode of PC computers, sometimes known as [DOS code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page#DOS_code_pages). I can't find a simple way to [run a program that wants a DOS code page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224162/how-to-get-the-old-ascii-characters-table-cp437). (Some terminals, including xterm but not Gnome-terminal, support 8-bit code pages via [`luit`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/luit.1.html). But Ubuntu does not come with locale definitions for DOS code pages.) You can use [`iconv`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/iconv.1.html) or [`recode`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/recode.1.html) to convert between a DOS code page and UTF-8, e.g.

```
my_program_that_outputs_cp437 | iconv -f CP437
```

If you're writing a program today, unless you need compatibility with 20th century software, use Unicode and UTF-8. So if you want ■ (BLACK SQUARE), it's code point 25A0. Since UTF-8 uses more than one byte per character, you need `puts()`, not `putchar()`: a “char” in C is a single byte.

```
puts("■");
```

`putchar(254)` prints nothing because it's an unfinished UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

C (also C++, etc) is quite annoying -- a single Unicode character isn't one "character". As Unicode uses more than one byte to store a single character, you cannot use functions that only support one "character" like `putchar`. Consider other printing functions, like `printf` as Alex said.

Of course, your terminal has to support Unicode, lol.

Comment: _"As Unicode uses more than one byte to store a single character"_ - Not necessarily. `a` in UTF-8 is a single byte.

Comment: @marcelm Sorry, I mean, those not in ASCII. Unicode is ASCII-compatible, so ASCII characters can store in a single byte.

Comment: @Emoji I think people (incl. me) object to you not distinguishing character sets and encodings. Unicode is a character set, nothing else than a table of all possible characters with associated IDs. As such, it does not specify any bit representation at all of those characters. It is, for example, UTF-8 -- an *encoding* -- that specifies how characters are encoded. UTF-8 is ASCII-compatible.